# Cloud Datalab fails to launch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Keep getting the following error when trying to launch Cloud Datalab. Tried deleting all listed VMs in the project, but still does not work.

```
Oct 27 10:50:31 datalab-deploy-main-20151027-10-41-31 startupscript: 10:50 AM Checking if updated app version is serving. 
Oct 27 10:50:31 datalab-deploy-main-20151027-10-41-31 startupscript: 10:50 AM Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: datalab:main.388142264345574525 
Oct 27 10:50:31 datalab-deploy-main-20151027-10-41-31 startupscript: ERROR: Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: datalab:main.388142264345574525 
Oct 27 10:50:31 datalab-deploy-main-20151027-10-41-31 startupscript: 10:50 AM Rolling back the update. This can sometimes take a while since a VM version is being rolled back. 
Oct 27 10:50:32 datalab-deploy-main-20151027-10-41-31 startupscript: Could not start serving the given version. 
Oct 27 10:50:32 datalab-deploy-main-20151027-10-41-31 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1] 
Oct 27 10:50:32 datalab-deploy-main-20151027-10-41-31 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only Managed VM deployed in your project? If so, I wonder if we can try cleaning up the managed VM storage bucket and give it another try: Go to Developer Console, storage, browse, and find the 2 buckets starting with "vm-config" and "vm-containers". Delete those buckets and try deploying Datalab again.

Sometimes there are permission issues with these 2 buckets when they were created. If that happened, Managed VM deployment fails due to being unable to pull images from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Nope, still does not work. Same errors as before. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by a permissions issue and might have been fixed recently. Could you give it another try? If it still fails with the same error, try the following:

1. Go to Developer Console, Permissions, under "Service Accounts", find the account [project-id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
2. Copy the account id to somewhere else since we'll use it later. Then remove the account from the list, make sure it disappears from the list, and add it back with "Can edit" permission.
3. Wait for a few minutes and try deploying Datalab again.

Let me know how it goes!